# How do I find out which package contains an executable?

Tags: package-management

Suppose I want to use the command eg. from the project `info2html` and it's not available on my system. Some distro's sometimes suggest packages for some missing commands that are expected (ie. considered common), but not for all commands (and not all distros).

How do I find out if there is a package for the desired program in my distribution, and if yes, which package do I need to install? Is there, what is the 'right way' to do this?

Some examples with specific distros like Debian are welcome. :)
It may depend on the package management software. 
Useful terminology is also welcome, so I can find this functionality in a given package ecosystem.

Comment: I disagree with this being a duplicate. The previous question asks only about Debian. I came here looking for how to find the containing package on a RedHat machine. The chosen answer answers that wonderfully, and (though it might be in the answers to the "question [that] already has answers", it is not a logical response to the question asked there.

Comment: I would never have clicked on the link to the other Q&A [ How to find out which (not installed) Debian package a file belongs to?" ], because I wouldn't have thought it would let me know how to complete the task on an RPM-based distro.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Depends on the platform.

Deb based:

```
apt-file search info2html
```

RPM based:

```
yum whatprovides info2html
```

IPS (Solaris 11, OpenIndiana, OmniOS, etc) based:

```
pkg search info2html
```

FreeBSD (OpenBSD?):

```
cd /usr/ports
make search key=info2html
```

NetBSD, SmartOS:

```
pkg_search info2html
```

Gentoo Linux:

```
emerge --search info2html
```

Comment: Arch Linux: `pkgfile -si info2html`

Comment: `apt-file search apt-file` :-( --> https://packages.debian.org/sid/apt-file

Comment: Note that recent RedHat/RPM based distros also use `sudo dnf whatprovides info2html`.

Comment: "*But how do I find which package provides `apt-file`, if I don't have `apt-file`?*" On Debian, `apt-file` is provided by the *apt-file* package: `sudo apt install apt-file`. After its installation, its database needs to be initialized once: `sudo apt-file update`.